# 802.1x setup on CentOS 7

Tags: networking, ethernet, hostapd, 802.1x, freeradius

I am currently trying to set up a 802.1x authentication server (FreeRADIUS) and authenticator (hostapd) on the same machine, and am running into some issues.

I have the RADIUS server set up along with hostapd. I have an 8 Ethernet ports (no wifi hardware available), and I can't seem to get hostapd to negotiate the Ethernet traffic with the RADIUS server.

It passes the initial negotiation (when I start the hostapd application), and sees whenever a link is connected/disconnected. But FreeRADIUS is not receiving any queries.
I have

(see below)

specified in the config, and when I execute I use -i to point at one of my Ethernet interfaces (not completely sure why I have to do this... wouldn't start otherwise)
I have strict requirements, so unfortunately I cannot include an Ethernet switch in this setup.

I appreciate any help/implementation ideas.

Thanks!

-edit-
Full config:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
driver=wired
interface=
channel=

ieee8021x=1

use_pae_group_addr=1

# The own IP address of the access point (used as NAS-IP-Address)
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1

# Optional NAS-Identifier string for RADIUS messages. When used, this should be
# a unique to the NAS within the scope of the RADIUS server. For example, a
# fully qualified domain name can be used here.
nas_identifier=ap.example.com

# RADIUS authentication server
auth_server_addr=127.0.0.1
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=testing

# RADIUS accounting server
acct_server_addr=127.0.0.1
acct_server_port=1813
acct_server_shared_secret=testing
```

Comment: I feel like you should post your hostapd.conf so it can be scrutinized.

Comment: No problem,. just added it. @Spiff

Comment: What are you using as your wired 802.1X supplicant? If you run a sniffer, do you see the 802.1X exchange happening? Do you see the eapol-start, the Identity Request, and especially the Identity Response? I wouldn't expect to see a RADIUS Access Request until after a valid EAPOL Identity Response has been received. You mentioned connecting and disconnecting the link, but you didn't say anything about seeing any 802.1X packets from the 802.1X supplicant.

Comment: I was using another CentOS machine as my supplicant, I was looking at it's wpa_supplicant logs, but did not run a sniffer. I will do that right when I'm at the setup again and post back. I just was expecting the link to be dropped when invalid credentials were passed to hostapd->radius. Instead the link came up and I was able to talk between them. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. I ran Wireshark while plugging the supplicant into my machine, and saw no 802.1x traffic at all. The only traffic I see was when I ping between the two machines. hostapd is running and recognizes when a device is plugged in or removed, however not passing any 802.1x traffic. Any ideas? @Spiff

Comment: Hmm. No traffic at all means two problems. The authenticator (hostapd) should send an identity request as soon as it sees the link come up, and the supplicant should send an eapol-start as soon as it sees the link come up, especially if it doesn't see an identity request right away. I wish I knew more about Linux's low-level plumbing for this, like what code is supposed to filter out (drop) everything but 802.1X frames until auth succeeds?

Comment: Well I’m not surprised that the supplicant isn’t starting the eapol-start, because I don’t have it fully configured for 802.1x. I was expecting hostapd to deny the traffic until a proper auth went through. Maybe I’ll configure the supplicant appropriately and see how hostapd responds. My next plan is to investigate how difficult it would be for me to intercept the traffic and do the 802.1x auth myself. However, hostapd should be able to do everything I want, correct? Thanks.

Comment: LOLOL I just looked at the driver_wired.c file in the hostapd sources, and it's clear their implementation is just experimental and I don't think it even tries to be secure (bummer for a security technology). I can't tell that they block non-EAPOL frames from unauthenticated MAC addresses, and apparently they don't detect unauthenticated devices unless those devices send DHCP traffic! hahahaaa. So if your supplicant box had a manual static IP address, and never sent a DHCP Discover or an eapol-start, that would explain why you never saw hostapd send an identity-request. Sorry to bear bad news.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for looking at that. I see their TODO to fix that DHCP requirement haha. My next steps will be to explore either improving hostapd, or try to tackle this problem from the driver/kernel level. Thanks again :)